# sqlite exception error SELECT command

Tags: android, sqlite, select

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, FROM TRACKS WERE _id=9

 String test = "SELECT _id, FROM TRACKS WERE _id="+"9";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(test, null);
```

Did not see the Point :( any help

Maybe there is a error in my Statement but it didn't work

Comment: That comma looks out of place `_id,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comma after `id` and `WERE` should be `WHERE`.
Also consider using [rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], android.os.CancellationSignal)] with `selectionArgs` to avoid having to concatenate query and values as you did in `+id=+9`.

Comment: Ok, now I have all done - and the command seems to work - seems error is in another line :( thank you anyway to all three

Answer (score 2):

> SELECT _id, FROM TRACKS WERE _id="+"9"

'WERE' should be WHERE

Comment: So sad - i would like to program and I'm blind :)) thank you but it didn't Change anything - same error